# What is this limit (fundamental theorem of calculus)

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, chain-rule

$lim_{x\to\ 1} \frac{f(x)}{lnx}$

$f(x)= \int_1^u e^{-sin t}dt$

$u=x^2$

I found out that limit will be $\frac{0}{lnx}=0$ is that correct?

Comment: Notice as you apply the limit, the bounds go from 1 to 1. The integral covers no area, so it is zero. However, note that $\ln(x)$ also drops to zero. So, you have an indeterminate form.

Comment: Yes, so that gives 0, right?

Comment: The best way to solve this limit is apply the L'Hospitals rule.

Comment: @Kaynex But the denominator goes also to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), one gets
$$
\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\left(\int_1^{x^2}e^{-\sin(t)}dt\right)'}{(\ln x)'}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{2x \cdot e^{-\sin(x^2)}}{\frac1x}=2e^{-\sin(1)}.
$$

Comment: thanks a lot, you edited your answer so many times that you forgot to write $\frac{f(x)}{lnx}$

Comment: @Emigsfd You are welcome. Apparently, I considered $f$ being the *whole given quotient*. The above answer is not edited ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's use L'Hospital rule.

we have

$f(x)=F(x^2)$ with

$$F(x)=\int_1^x e^{-\sin(t)}dt$$

thus

$$f'(x)=2xF'(x^2)=2xe^{-\sin(x^2)}$$

and the limit is

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)}{\ln(x)}=\lim_{x\to1}xf'(x)=2e^{-\sin(1)}$$